# AlarmManager не работает при не рабочем Activity

Tags: android, уведомления

Устанавливаю AlarmManager. Задаю ему Brodcastreciver. Всё работает, когда приложение включено, или свёрнуто, но если его закрыть уведомления перестают приходить и соответственно не выполняется AlarmManager. В чём может быть причина?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification_reciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

UPDATE

Notification_reciever.class объявлен как рессивер в манифесте, отдельный класс наследующий Brodcastreciver

Телефон Xiaomi Redmi 4a

```
force stop
```

не объявлялось

Comment: Мало информации для ответа. Ресивер у вас в активити объявлен или в манифесте? Это отдельный класс, или поле в активити? Закрытие приложения это не `force stop`? MIUI оболочки не стоит? И ещё много вопросов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вопрос

Comment: Тут дело может быть в особенностях оболочки MIUI. Попробуйте в настройках оной поставить приоритет вашему приложению повыше и/или перепишите на `JobScheduller` - это теперь надо через него делать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Поискал, не смог найти как делать JobScheduller под будильник. Нету ли у тебя примеров ?

Comment: Примеров нет, сам не пробовал такое делать